# Why is the compositing window white and how do I get nodes?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm new to blender, when i press the compositing tab I get this:

I can't find the nodes, where are they?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a large image connected to the Viewer node.
Try pressing V for some time until the image gets smaller and reveals the comp grid.

When this works use your MB3 to search for the Nodes. If nothing is there add them in with Shift + A

Comment: Hey that works, Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the background?
If you look at the big X in the middle of the field it normaly indicates, that a Viewer node is used at the moment. Normaly you would A) Remove the Viewer node. B) Scale the viewer node down with pressing V. 
Otherwise the Field should be black